# Integration of Legendre polynomials using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Do you know how I could find the solution to the integral

```
Integral_(-1)^1 (LegendreP(n, x) LegendreP(m, x))/(1-x^2) dx
```

using MATLAB? I know that with Mathematica it'is pretty easy but I do not have access to it. I tried it in different ways using MATLAB but it does not seem to work.

Comment: What is m and n? Or do you seek an analytical solution?

Comment: n and m are not specified, yes i am seeking of an analytical solutions.there are tables that include these kind of solutions but not this one so I have to find it "numerically"

Comment: For a numerical solution you need to know a numerical value for m and n.

Comment: yes that is why I wrote "numerically" :). I know mathematica does this sort of "calculations" and I was wondering if I could do the same using MATLAB

Comment: Ok, but you cannot solve it numerically without knowing m and n. So could you specify those?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, if I specify them I can solve the problem, I am seeking for an analytical solution of the product of two legendre polynomials of order n and m with weight function 1/(1-x^2). I guess it cannot be done with MATLAB then since I have to specify these values unlike MATHEMATICA

Comment: Can't you just use the symbolic math toolbox?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!Mathematica cannot do it either?That seems weird. I cannot specify the m and n unfortunately i need the general solution

Comment: I tried, but Mathematica is also not able to solve it analytically.